# How to deserialize nested Kotlin objects on the RestController?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, kotlin

In a `RestController` component of a Spring application I have function that requires a nested object as parameter.

This is the code

```
@RestController
class AdController {

    @GetMapping(path = ["/hi"])
    fun sayHello(userRequest: UserRequest): String {
        return  "Hello ${userRequest.name} - ${userRequest.nested!!.nestedValue}"
    }
}

data class UserRequest(val name: String, val nested: NestedObject)
data class NestedObject(var nestedValue: String)
```

This API is called by the client passing all the parameters as query string

```sh
curl localhost:8080/hi\?name=Tom&nested.nestedValue=Berlin
```

Spring should be smart enough to deserialize the two nested object, but seems it has some trouble. Because the answer is:

```
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null
```

To make it work I had to give up using the nice&save Kotlin syntax and make everything `nullable`.

```
class UserRequest {
    var name: String? = null
    var nested: NestedObject? = null
}

class NestedObject {
    var nestedValue: String? = null
}
```

In this way it works, but I would rather have a more defined nullability on my models.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the request method, it a bad practice to use GET in such case, I will recommend a `POST` method with a `request body` to be able to deserialize an object

```
@PostMapping(path = ["/hi"])
fun sayHello(@RequestBody userRequest: UserRequest): String {
    return  "Hello ${userRequest.name} - ${userRequest.nested!!.nestedValue}"
}
```

Comment: I don't think is a bad practice. The difference between GET/POST should be based on the effect that this request does. And in this case this isn't a POST.